# How to make JOINS faster?

Tags: mysql

I had this query to start out with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT spentits.*
FROM `spentits`
WHERE (spentits.user_id IN
         (SELECT following_id
          FROM `follows`
          WHERE `follows`.`follower_id` = '44'
            AND `follows`.`accepted` = 1)
       OR spentits.user_id = '44')
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
```

This query takes `10ms` to execute.

But once I add a simple join in:

```
SELECT DISTINCT spentits.*
FROM `spentits`
LEFT JOIN wishlist_items ON wishlist_items.user_id = 44 AND wishlist_items.spentit_id = spentits.id
WHERE (spentits.user_id IN
         (SELECT following_id
          FROM `follows`
          WHERE `follows`.`follower_id` = '44'
            AND `follows`.`accepted` = 1)
       OR spentits.user_id = '44')
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
```

This execute time increased by `11x`. Now it takes around `120ms` to execute. What's interesting is that if I remove either the `LEFT JOIN` clause **or** the `ORDER BY id DESC` , the time goes back to `10ms`.

I am new to databases so I don't understand this. Why is it that removing either one of these clauses speeds it up `11x` ? And how can I keep it as is but make it faster?

I have indexes on `spentits.user_id`, `follows.follower_id`, `follows.accepted`, and on `primary ids` of each table.

**EXPLAIN:**

```
1   PRIMARY spentits    index   index_spentits_on_user_id   PRIMARY 4   NULL    15 Using where; Using temporary
1   PRIMARY wishlist_items  ref index_wishlist_items_on_user_id,index_wishlist_items_on_spentit_id  index_wishlist_items_on_spentit_id  5   spentit.spentits.id 1   Using where; Distinct
2   SUBQUERY    follows index_merge index_follows_on_follower_id,index_follows_on_following_id,index_follows_on_accepted

index_follows_on_follower_id,index_follows_on_accepted  5,2 NULL    566 Using intersect(index_follows_on_follower_id,index_follows_on_accepted); Using where
```

Comment: What does EXPLAIN PLAN show?

Comment: @DavidJashi updated with EXPLAIN

Answer (score 3):

You should have index also on:

> wishlist_items.spentit_id

Because you are joining over that column

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to list it, but I do have it indexed.

Answer (score 0):

The LEFT JOIN is easy to explain: A cross product of all entries against all other entries is made. The conditions of the join (in your case: Take all entries on the left and find fitting ones on the right) are applied afterwards. So if your spentits table is large it will take the server some time. Would suggest you get rid of your subquery and make three joins. Start with the smallest table to avoid big amounts of data.

Comment: `A cross product of all entries against all other entries is made` - That is CROSS JOIN, not LEFT JOIN

Comment: Also, doing 2 JOINS (joining on follows instead os subquery) kills the performance. It takes around 350 ms to execute.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd example the subselect runs for every spentits.user_id.

If you write is like this it will be faster because the subselect runs once:

```
SELECT DISTINCT spentits.*
FROM `spentits`, (SELECT following_id
          FROM `follows`
          WHERE `follows`.`follower_id` = '44'
            AND `follows`.`accepted` = 1)
       OR spentits.user_id = '44') as `follow`
LEFT JOIN wishlist_items ON wishlist_items.user_id = 44 AND wishlist_items.spentit_id = spentits.id
WHERE (spentits.user_id IN
         (follow)
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
```

As you can see the subselect moved to the FROM-part of the query and creates a imaginary tabel (or view).
This imaginary tabel is a inline-view.

JOINs and inline-views are faster every time than a subselect in the WHERE-part.

Comment: Getting 'Unknown column 'follow' in 'where clause''

Comment: You are right. There is a mistake with a '(' and the IN operator does not match wiht tabels.

Comment: Try this please:
    
SELECT DISTINCT spentits.*
FROM `spentits`, (SELECT following_id
          FROM `follows`
          WHERE `follows`.`follower_id` = '44'
            AND `follows`.`accepted` = 1)
       OR spentits.user_id = '44') as `follow`
LEFT JOIN wishlist_items ON wishlist_items.user_id = 44 AND wishlist_items.spentit_id = spentits.id
WHERE spentits.user_id = follow.following_id
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0

Comment: That works, but still response time is 100ms. This is because you are STILL doing a JOINS and not IN.  spentits.user_id = follow.following_id is a joins.